# How to add menu items for publishing iste

Tags: sharepoint-designer, publishing-site, css, dropdown

I created on publishing site. Now I want to add menu bar over there. But publishing site doesn't contain menu bar by default. How to add this into publishing site. I tried to add from v4.master page but failed. Could you please tell me the way to do it? I want to display following items in publishing site. Menu items in the following image are in vertical. But i want to convert them into horizontal or just like team site menu items. How to achieve?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry Mihir I misread, you need to look at the [MSDN real world branding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/gg430141.aspx) post.

Code from MSDN:

```
<div class="customTopNavHolder">
<PublishingNavigation:PortalSiteMapDataSource
  ID="topSiteMap"
  runat="server"
  EnableViewState="false"
  SiteMapProvider="GlobalNavigation"
  StartFromCurrentNode="true"
  StartingNodeOffset="0"
  ShowStartingNode="false"
  TrimNonCurrentTypes="Heading"/>

 <SharePoint:AspMenu
   ID="TopNavigationMenuV4"
   Runat="server"
   EnableViewState="false"
   DataSourceID="topSiteMap"
   AccessKey="<%$Resources:wss,navigation_accesskey%>"
   UseSimpleRendering="true"
   UseSeparateCss="false"
   Orientation="Horizontal"
   StaticDisplayLevels="1"
   MaximumDynamicDisplayLevels="1" 
   SkipLinkText=""
   CssClass="s4-tn">
 </SharePoint:AspMenu> 
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much... really Useful link what you provided. Great brother...

Answer (score 0):

I think, you are using Publishing site so using nightandday.master file as master page.
which does not contain sharepoint menu by default. but yes, you can inject by customizing code like:

```
<SharePoint:AspMenu
  ID="TopNavigationMenuV4"
  Runat="server"
  EnableViewState="false"
  DataSourceID="topSiteMap"
  AccessKey="<%$Resources:wss,navigation_accesskey%>"
  UseSimpleRendering="true"
  UseSeparateCss="false"
  Orientation="Horizontal"
  StaticDisplayLevels="2"
  MaximumDynamicDisplayLevels="1"
  SkipLinkText=""
  CssClass="s4-tn"/>
```

Comment: Yeah I tried with this one. But it is saying topsitemap is not exist. That topsitemap also i copied and pasted.. but not working properly

Answer (score 0):

I have tried your same scenario in local machine, and i got solution. 
You may be editing existing AspMenu from nightandday.master reference master file.

But you need to add some code for Global menu:

```
<SharePoint:AspMenu
              ID="TopNavigationMenuV4"
              Runat="server"
              EnableViewState="false"
              DataSourceID="topSiteMap"
              AccessKey="<%$Resources:wss,navigation_accesskey%>"
              UseSimpleRendering="true"
              UseSeparateCss="false"
              Orientation="Horizontal"
              StaticDisplayLevels="2"
              MaximumDynamicDisplayLevels="1"
              SkipLinkText=""
              CssClass="s4-tn"/>
              <SharePoint:DelegateControl runat="server" ControlId="TopNavigationDataSource" Id="topNavigationDelegate">
            <Template_Controls>
                <asp:SiteMapDataSource
                  ShowStartingNode="False"
                  SiteMapProvider="SPNavigationProvider"
                  id="topSiteMap"
                  runat="server"
                  StartingNodeUrl="sid:1002"/>
            </Template_Controls>
```

After that you can make visible false to your current asp menu which is vertical if you dont need.

Hope it is useful to you. let me know if you still getting any issue.